# Передача структуры в функцию потока

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность, структуры

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx;

void* process(void *args)
{ 
    //тут нужно принять структуру
    printf("thread\n");     
}

void main(void)
{
    pthread_t thr;         
    char S1[20], S2[20];
    char sp = " ";
    gets(S1);
    gets(S2);

    istr = strtok(S1,sp); 

    while(istr != NULL)//перебираем все слова
    {
       struct pthread_data{
           char slovo[20];
           char str[20];
       }pthread_data;
       //тут структуре нужно присвоить значение переменных слова и строки 
       //далее вместо NULL нужно передать структуру из слова и строки
       pthread_create(&thr,NULL,process,NULL);
       pthread_join(thr, NULL);
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Как правильно передать структуру в функцию потока и там прочитать ее?

Пытаюсь таким вот образом, но не получается, ругается на присвоение threadData[i].slovo = istr, пишет "assignment to expression with array type"

```
typedef struct{
    char slovo[20];
    char str[20];
} pthrData;


void* process(void* thread_data)
{ 
    pthrData *data = (pthrData*) thread_data;

    ... 
 }

void main(void)
    {

    while(istr != NULL)//перебираем все слова, т е потоков должно быть столько, колько слов
    {
       pthrData* threadData = (pthrData*) malloc(sizeof(pthrData));
       threadData[i].slovo = istr;
       threadData[i].str = S2;   
       //тут вместо нул нужно передать структуру из слова и строки
       pthread_create(&thr,NULL,process,&threadData[i]);
       pthread_join(thr, NULL);
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
       i++;
    } 

}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так передать ее адрес, в чем проблема?

Только структура не должна быть локальной переменной!

Сделайте ее, например, динамически выделенной, а в потоке, когда будет не нужна, удалите.

**Update** 
После вашего обновления...

```
while(istr != NULL)//перебираем все слова, т е потоков должно быть столько, колько слов
{
   pthrData* threadData = (pthrData*) malloc(sizeof(pthrData));
   strncpy(threadData[i].slovo,istr,20); // По-хорошему, нужно еще и нуль-символ дописать
   strncpy(threadData[i].str,S2,20);   
   pthread_create(&thr,NULL,process,&threadData[i]);

   // А вот тут вы ждете выполнение потока. Так что все потоки у вас будут работать по очереди. Параллельности не будет.
   pthread_join(thr, NULL);

   istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Сильно же будет разочарование ТС от падения производительности по сравнению с однопоточной версией.

Comment: Ну, это уже второй вопрос. Все равно надо учиться никуда не передавать адреса локальных переменных, а то ведь можно привыкнуть...

Comment: Это не догма. От задачи зависит. Иногда (если повторно не используется) вполне можно.

Comment: @avp Ну так ведь и выпить иногда по случаю праздника можно :) Но привычку пить лучше не приобретать...

Comment: @avp Не получается структуре присвоить переменную, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: См. обновленный ответ...

Comment: @Harry, а можно ли из функции потока вернуть значение переменной?

Comment: @ВадимМороз, функция может записывать результат в ту же структуру, которая передаётся ей аргументом. Но сдаётся мне что вы вообще куда-то не туда копаете...

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте смотрел в сторону `async` из стандартной библиотеки С++. Но! сколько у вас ядер? делать потоков больше, чем количество ядер, - занятие для вычислительной задачи бессмысленное. Вряд ли вы очень много выгадаете на распараллеливании, и уж точно не больше чем в N раз, где N - количество ядер.

Comment: @avp, вы не знаете случайно почему программа с потоками работает гораздо медленнее обычной, хотя в теории вроде должно быть наоборот?

Comment: Накладные расходы. Реально выигрыш начинается с десятков тысяч  (а то и сотен тысяч)  операций в созданном потоке, исполняющимся параллельно. В вашем  же коде вообще ничего полезного  параллельно не исполняется.